# How to use Set-Location on a folder with trailing spaces in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, path, cd, trailing-whitespace

I have mounted a linux shared folder. In the folder, there is a sub-folder `. \` (dot space) which I need to access. With the command prompt I can access it using the 8dot3 notation of short names, but I need to access it with PowerShell.

`Set-Location` and `cd` will throw an error on paths with folder names with trailing spaces (path does not exist).

Comment: Try with `Set-Location -LiteralPath '. \\'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows still does not have the best support for folder names with trailing spaces. You can use a workaround with symbolic links. Create a symbolic link to the folder that contains a trailing space in its name using the `mklink` command of an elevated Windows command prompt (not available in PS as it is a command and not a tool) and define your path as a [UNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Universal_Naming_Convention) path:

```
mklink /D C:\MyLink "\\?\C:\path\to\folder\. "
```

After that you can do:

```
cd C:\MyLink
```

or:

```
Set-Location -LiteralPath C:\MyLink
```

in PowerShell to work from your directory that has a trailing space in its name.

You can read more on operations with folder names containing trailing spaces in my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1550630/1077440).

Comment: This helps, I was able to access the folder. I also created a symbolic link to the specific file i need.